# javascript: how to detect environment on server side pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailchimp, production-environment

I've inherited a react/javascript app and I'd like to make a small change to export different mailchimp account variables for prod vs test environments, in mailchimp-configuration.js. (These values get imported from src/server/index.js)

I updated mailchimp-configuration.js to check whether process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'. This works, but it isn't quite right since I can run my local sandbox (or staging) server 'as production', in which case the production account gets used instead of the test one. I need to use something more conclusive that'll know whether we're running in the production environment vs staging or localhost.

An easy solution on the browser pages is to check the url via window.location.href, but unfortunately from mailchimp-configuration.js, window is not defined.

I suppose I could set a global variable somewhere, but that's last-resort stuff. What's a good way to check my environment from the server side?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use something more conclusive that'll know whether we're running in the production environment vs staging or localhost.

There is technically no difference between "a nodejs instance running on a computer" and "a nodejs instance running on a computer". The only way to distinguish "your localhost" and "a production server" is to tell the nodejs instance where it runs in, and thats done by `process.ENV`.

> I updated mailchimp-configuration.js to check whether process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'. This works, but it isn't quite right since I can run my local sandbox (or staging) server 'as production', in which case the production account gets used instead of the test one.

Actually this is the way to go, if you fear that your secret email account gets used by a test server, then that secret should actually go into a secret manager, such as [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of node's native os functions and determine according to a certain value if you are running node locally in dev -> [Link](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html)

Standard practice is to set an environmental variable to the according environment you're in (production or development).

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```

perform  a check:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
// do dev stuff
} 
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
//do production stuff
}
```

Comment: thanks, @iLuvLogix! It sounds like my approach *is* the usual way (good to know, since all of this is new to me!) so in this case I'll need to get around the issue that our staging environment runs as production by either updating staging to have a different NODE_ENV value, or leave it as is and add/use a second variable to set the mailchimp info. Thanks!

Comment: @Diane Kaplan: It's a pleasure ;) Hope you have lots of fun with node in the future - the learning curve is quite a steep one with this framework!